# "Attempted Frozen Title Change", but title is the same

Tags: facebook

I have a like button on this site:
http://seznam-autobusu.cz/dokumentacka/93412

Month ago, it has over 100 likes. Now, it has one.

I tried to check URL in FB Open Graph Object Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and it tells me:

> It appears that you are trying to change the property og:title from
>   Fotografie: Karosa C734.00 02V 0606 Jaroslav Staněk, Suchý u Boskovic
>   | Suchý u Boskovic to Fotografie: Karosa C734.00 02V 0606 Jaroslav
>   Staněk, Suchý u Boskovic | Suchý u Boskovic. If so, you are not
>   allowed to for this object because too many actions have been
>   published against it.

However, two titles, which are presented to be different, seems to be the same for me.

What am I supposed to do?

I think it's possible, that the change was in some whitespaces on something like this. Facebook should ignore changes in whitespaces cause it is not a significant change.

Have you ever seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between old and new og:title was in whitespaces, so it is not visible in Object Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything different here.

This error message shouldn't be appearing.

File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Bug reported: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1512696162352263/
I am very curious... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by whitespace at the end of the title, or by double spaces. When Facebook first gets the info, it strips out any unnecessary whitespace. When Facebook re-scrapes your page, it compares the title to the title it has stored. As the stored version is stripped, and the version it is comparing is unstripped, the two strings will not match.

Just another example of the intellect of Facebook programmers.